# SQL - Update row based on rank values

Tags: sql, postgresql

The case is specific for postgres, but I think it applies for SQL-ansi

I have data like this:

```
id_log  |command    |date                   |state
1       |action1    |2017-05-04 09:59:28    
2       |action1    |2017-05-04 09:59:29    SUCCESS
3       |action2    |2017-05-04 10:00:22    
4       |action2    |2017-05-04 10:00:24    FAILURE
```

for example, ids 1 and 2 are the two steps of the same request, id 1 is the request itself and id 2 is the result. Basically the first step (id 1 for example) does not have any status.

I want to set the id 1 with SUCCESS just like the response (and for the rest of the records); I'm thinking of add a custom id with 'rank() over', something like this:

```
id_log  |command    |date                   |state  |step   |set_command_id
1       |action1    |2017-05-04 09:59:28                1       1
2       |action1    |2017-05-04 09:59:29    SUCCESS     2       1
3       |action2    |2017-05-04 10:00:22                1       2
4       |action2    |2017-05-04 10:00:24    FAILURE     2       2
```

and then use that to set Ids 1 and 3 with success and failure, respectively

is it a good approach? how can I achieve this?

Comment: You mention you want to set the ID of 1 with SUCCESS, but your sample output does not have ID 1 set to SUCESS?

Comment: It's unclear to me if `step` and `set_command_id` are actual columns in the table that you want to change using `UPDATE` or if you just want to generated values in the result of a `SELECT` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name step and set_command_id are the result of a with statement applying rank; I just thought that could help to identify the set of records "request-response"; step 1 for id_log 1 is the request, step 2 for the id_log 2 is the response; set_command_id is to mark out that the're from the same request-response set

Comment: @NatyBizz . . . What happens if the requests are interleaved? Or if you have more than one `action1` request?

Comment: @GordonLinoff fortunately the requests are in perfect order; otherwise the solution would be far more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can produce the extra `step` and `set_command_id` as described using:

```
select
  *,
  row_number() over(partition by command order by date) as step,
  dense_rank() over(order by command) as set_command_id
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5260adb96f34a57eeb3787f8f5a280e6)

You can use [`row_number()` and `dense_rank()` window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    *,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY command ORDER BY log_date) AS step,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY command) AS set_command_id
FROM
    log
```

`row_number()` creates row count within the group and `dense_rank()` adds a consecutive unique id per group (in this case `command`)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a group-and-islands problem -- but the issue is not obvious because you have only two groups that are not interleaved.

I think you can identify the groups by counting the number of `state = NULL` values up to each row.  The rest is then just window functions:

```
select l.*,
       dense_rank() over (min_log_date, command) as set_command_id,
       row_number() over (partition by command, grouping order by log_date) as step
from (select l.*,
             min(log_date) over (partition by command, grouping) as min_log_date
      from (select l.*,
                   sum( (state is null)::int ) over (partition by command order by log_date) as grouping
            from log l
           ) l
     ) l
```